# I tried running this code from Learn-C.org in Sublime Text and I get these errors

Tags: c, variables

I just signed up and at the moment I'm learning C language.
I messed around with formatting and trying different variables. That didn't work. If someone could point out the obvious here, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    int a = 3;
    float b = 4.5;
    double c = 5.25;
    float sum;
    sum = a + b + c; 

printf("The sum of a, b, and c is %f.", sum);
return 0;
}
```

**error: expected ',' or ';' before 'float'
float sum;**

**error: 'sum' undeclared (first use in this function)
sum = a + b + c;**

note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: Did you remember to save the file before compiling? Works fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/6rWj177za

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't have any syntax errors and runs successfully as seen here

https://onlinegdb.com/w57JOqkgc

Make sure you save the changes you made before compiling / running.